# Data validating in firestore security rules, refuse if unknown data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
match /my-data/{userId}
{
  allow write: if "name" in request.resource.data;
}
```

This above validates if name is in the data. But it also allows any other data to be written along with "name". What do I do if I ***only*** want *name* in the data, and if any other data is provided, then deny write operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`List.hasOnly` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasOnly), which allows you to ensure a list has only certain members.

Something like this:

```
request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly("name")
```

---

If the document can already contain any fields, but only the `name` field is allowed to be modified, you'll want to combine `hasOnly` wih the [`map.diff()` operation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#expandable-3).

So that'd be something like this:

```
resource.data.diff(request.resource.data).keys().hasOnly("name")
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a little typo there on the keys() as its a method: *request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly("name")*

Comment: Oops, good catch  I fixed it in the answer too.